# INSERT INTO via formulário Erro

Tags: php

Estou tentando inserir dados via formulário no PHP. Porém, estou com um erro, não estou conseguindo achar esse erro de maneira alguma.

Como eu disse, eu estou querendo inserir dados, via o `SELECT INTO`

Observe:

inserir.php, é nessa aba que eu irei inserir os dados.

```
<h3>Formulário de Cadastro de Sinaps</h3><br>
  <form name="Cadastro" action="insere_dados.php" method="POST">
    <label>Nome do programa: </label>
    <input type="text" name="programa" size="30"><br>
    <label>versa do programa: </label>
    <input type="text" name="versaoprograma" size="45"><br>
    <label>Data de Publicação: </label>
    <input type="text" name="data" size="45"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

insere_dados.php, essa aba irá fazer a função do inserir.php

```
<?php
$programa = $_POST['programa'];
$versaoprograma = $_POST['versaoprograma'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','atualizacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = "INSERT INTO geral (nomedopograma, versaodoprograma, datadoprograma) VALUES ('$programa', '$versaoprograma', '$data')";
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($strcon);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
?>
```

atualizao.php, essa aba ira receber os dados do inserir.php

```
<?php

// Propriedades BD

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "");
define("BDNAME", "atualizacao");

@mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS) or die("Não foi possivel se conectar ao servidor");
mysql_select_db(BDNAME) or die("Não foi possível se conectar ao banco de dados") ;

?>


<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM geral");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo "<ul class='col-md-12 item1'>";

echo "<li class='nomedoprograma'>".$exibe["nomedoprograma"]."</li>";

echo "<li class='versao'>".$exibe["versaodoprograma"]."</li>";

echo "<li class='atualizacao'>".$exibe["datadoprograma"]."</li>";

echo "</ul>";

}
?>
```

Quando eu vou preencher os dados e clico em enviar, a única mensagem que aparece é **Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro**,

Banco de dados

> ```
> -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
> -- version 4.6.4
> -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
> --
> -- Host: 127.0.0.1
> -- Generation Time: 24-Abr-2017 às 15:32
> -- Versão do servidor: 5.7.14
> -- PHP Version: 5.6.25
>
>
> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
> SET time_zone = "+00:00";
>
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
>
> --
> -- Database: `atualizacao`
> --
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Estrutura da tabela `geral`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `geral` (
>   `nomedoprograma` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>   `versaodoprograma` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>   `datadoprograma` date NOT NULL,
>   `comentarios` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> --
> -- Extraindo dados da tabela `geral`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `geral` (`nomedoprograma`, `versaodoprograma`, `datadoprograma`, `comentarios`) VALUES
> ('Sinap280', 'Versao 200', '2017-04-24', ''),
> ('Sinap280', 'Versao 200', '2017-04-24', ''),
> ('', 'versao100', '2017-04-24', ''),
> ('Sinap 8024', '1090', '2017-04-24', '');
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> ```

Esse é o banco de dados.

Comment: Durante o debug, troque o `die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");` por um que mostre o erro real retornado, que fica mais fácil: `die(mysqli_error($strcon));` - Isto para debug apenas, em produção não tem sentido revelar a estrutura da sua aplicação para o usuário final.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_close' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\Duotec - Sistemas\insere_dados.php on line 9 apareceu esse erro

Comment: na Verdade o erro é outro "Unknown column 'nomedopograma' in 'field list'" acho que ja descobri

Comment: É, falta um R lá. O mais importante é acostumar a usar o `mysql_error` para facilitar o desenvolvimento. E depois de pronto, tirar da saida de tela (e talvez mandar para log de erro, por exemplo)

Comment: Sim sim, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O erro é que estava faltando um "R" no nomedoprograma.

Código correto:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO geral (nomedoprograma, versaodoprograma, datadoprograma, comentarios) VALUES ('$programa', '$versaoprograma', '$data', '$coment')";
```